# Date format parsing java

Tags: java

I want to store today's date in the format yyyy-mm-dd. before storing I have took today's date,formatted it and again parse the formatted string to date. It gives the output date in a different format other than what I want. How can i get the date, format it in 'yyyy-mm-dd'
and again convert it into date and want the output in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.Please find the below code and tell  me where I am wrong

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.util.Date date1;
String datestring=dateFormat.format(date);

try {           
    date1=dateFormat.parse(datestring);
    System.out.print(date1);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(accordcclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The output for the above code I get is 
Thu Mar 07 00:00:00 GMT 2013. But I want the output as 2013-01-07

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, this is what I did:

```
DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
DateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(outputDateFormat.format(inputDateFormat.parse("09-SEP-2013 10:00")));
```

That way I can parse the date in the original format and output it in the database compatible format.

There is the posibility of using PreparedStatement as someone mentiones before but I don't want to.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a `Date` object to print, use directly your `datestring` variable. Using a `Date` will call `toString` which will be formatted using the `Locale`.

Edit : Adding that if you want to store your `Date` variable with a format, it doesn't work that way. A `Date` doesn't hold a format, it just represents the time. How you show it in a GUI, console or anywhere else is where you need to specify a format if you want it to differ from the current `Locale` format.

Comment: I want the output in a date type and in preferred format because i need to store the date in db. using directly the datestring will give me the value in string datatype, which is not my preferred datatype.

Comment: @crazyvi, `java.util.Date` doesnt have a preferred format. It's an internal representation in milliseconds since Jan 01, 1970. Can you show us your code that writes to the DB?

Comment: @crazyvi If you store the date in your db into a `String` field, when creating the insert or update statement, format the date as you do in your example. If the field is a `Date` or `TimeStamp`, you don't need to format it, the db will hold the value correctly. You only need to format to "show" the date as mentionned in my edit.

Comment: QueryString = "INSERT INTO APP.SIMPLETABLE VALUES ("+snolastvalue+",10,10,"+addfslastvalue+",'Food','Febraury',"+date+")"; is my query string where date is the placeholder where I wish to insert date in a preferred format.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau, my field in db is date type.

Comment: @crazyvi You don't need to format at all. When you save it into the db, the db will use its own format and when you'll resquest that date back from the db, you'll get a `Date` object which you can then format the way you want to show it. A `Date` just represents the time, it doesn't need a format until it is shown. Chat might be a better place to continue this if you need more help.

Comment: if i dint format the date, when i try to insert a date using insert into query string in java, it says Syntax error: Encountered "Mar" at line 1, column 72

Comment: @crazyvi I'm guessing from this that you construct a `String` for your request and then use it to update/insert into your db? You should use a `PreparedStatement` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) so you pass the `Date` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the DateFormat to format and reparse.

You don't need to re-parse. Simply use the DateFormat only to format.

```
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
  String datestring=dateFormat.format(date);
  System.out.println( datestring );
```

Comment: My db has a field with data datatype. I cannot insert datestring into that field. So i need to convert it into date dataype again. How can i do it?

Comment: You don't need to convert back into a Date - you already have a Date. But a Date holds only a time (as a long integer representing a number of milliseconds since a base time). A Date does not hold any formatted strings -- even if you create it by parsing a formatted string. If you need both a Date for your database, and a formatted string for your output, you're going to need two different objects.

Comment: if i dint format the date, when i try to insert a date using insert into query string in java, it says Syntax error: Encountered "Mar" at line 1, column 72.

Comment: See @Jonathan Drapeau's perceptive response to the same comment in his answer.