# convert string yyyy-MM-dd into date format with phone language right to left (Arabic)

Tags: java, android, date

This is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String exp_date="2015-08-28";
try {
    Log.v("dateformat111","is "+exp_date);
    Date exp_dateFormated = format.parse(exp_date);
    Log.v("dateformat111","is "+exp_dateFormated);       
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.v("dateformat111","did not found date");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the catch is being called so something went wrong

Log :

```
09-24 12:21:34.931  19014-19014/? V/dateformat111﹕ did not found date
```

Exception :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-28"
```

Not a duplicate of [How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172)
the string I'm parsing is the same format of SimpleDateFormat 
"yyyy-MM-dd" ,"2015-08-28"

I found out what is causing the exception 
with English (ltr) as phone language my code works
but when change it to Arabic (rtl) the exception is thrown, why is that?

Comment: Code is not throwing any exception.

Comment: Your code is fine, something must be wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah. Its working fine no issues found.

Comment: i'm working on a background service does that conflict wtih the main UI thread or something like that ?

Comment: What exception do you get? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: most probably locale issue

Comment: @Ahmedna - That's the log message you showed. What's the stack trace? after that?

Comment: i couldn't find the exception ,but the catch is being called , i know that from the log , i updated the question , it might be local and trying to find out, i read a lot about this and my cod should work, thanx

Comment: That's strange, I tried your code, and it's working fine.

Comment: @KarthikR java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-28" ,
and i updated question

Comment: @SergeyGlotov java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-28"

Comment: use only one 'd' and one 'M'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296150/date-format-parsing-java

Comment: @Ahmedna - I don't find any exceptions either. And code seems fine too :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

Comment: it was local , i updated question , why different langues effect the parsing ?and how to overcome that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem is due to invalid date in locale. try changing your locale as below.

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
```

It will work.

Comment: i have the same format of SimpleDateFormat and the string i'm trying to parse : "yyyy-MM-dd" ,"2015-08-28"

Comment: comment 2nd line in try block and make 3rd line as below `Log.v("dateformat111","is "+format.parse(exp_date));`

Comment: that question was trying to store date in a certain format ,i'm just trying to use it ,tried your cod and same exception , i found what is causing the exception ,my code is working with phone English language  (ltr),but when change the phone language to Arabic (rtl) exception get thrown the date format in arabic is different than "yyyy-MM-dd" ??

Comment: Whatever the locale returned by Locale.getDefault() is doesn't support dates formatted from arabic locale.

Changing it to Locale.US for example, will work.

Comment: i made it         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
and worked ! ,thanx ,edit your answer for easy access if you like

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Main.java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class DateFormate extends Activity {

    Button btnDate;
    TextView txtDate;

    String date="2015-9-25";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_formate);

        btnDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        txtDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btnDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date d;
                try {
                    d = df.parse(date);
                    df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String myDate = df.format(d);
                   Log.i("Date",myDate);
                   txtDate.setText(""+myDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {}
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dateformate.DateFormate" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="DateFormate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is working for me.

Comment: exception thrown again at  df.parse(date) ,java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Comment: i update question , your code worked perfectly with English langue for phone , but same exception with arabic(rtl)